# Not reading full web page content

Tags: java, connection

I'm trying to read a RSS content. I don't know why, the following code (java) isn't able to retrieve all the content.

The page starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="0.91">` and should end with `</rss>`, but I don't know why, it stops at `</rs`, or sometimes `</r` ...

The problem only occurs wiht a specific site (http://www.valor.com.br/financas/rss). And sometimes, even it works.

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.valor.com.br/financas/rss");
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

I'm quite sure that the problem isn't related with my code. Probably is related with some kind of network problem (I read almost 50 sites and just this one doesn't work), but I'm trying to find if my code could be more resilient.

Any suggestions/advice?

TIA,

Bob

Comment: Your code looks fine. I think this is a problem on their site - I just opened it up in my browser and got a `</r` at the end ...

Comment: So, if the server, in the browser, is giving you truncated results, then you don't really have any hope that your code will do any better. Not much you can do, especially since other users report the same issue.